# How do I store JSON data in an Underscore template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, templates, underscore.js

I would like to store a JSON object or string in an Underscore template.

```
<script id="report_field_template" type="text/template">
    <div data-options="<%= options %>" role="<%- role %>" title="<%- title %>" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all report_field">
        <p><%- field_text %></p>
    </div>
</script>
```

The above will not work if I pass "options" as a JSON string or a JSON object.  Any ideas?

Comment: I would make sure your options does not have any double quotes in it. You may need to use <%- to escape options as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to use single quotes when dealing with html5 data- attributes that house JSON data:

```
<script id="report_field_template" type="text/template">
    <div data-options='<%= options %>' role="<%- role %>" title="<%- title %>" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all report_field">
        <p><%- field_text %></p>
    </div>
</script>
```

Notice the single quotes around used to hold the value of data-options instead of double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to pass

```
{options: JSON.stringify(options)}
```

to the template :) After that you'll need to parse it back while reading.